# How to insert \n after the tag is closed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code I have:

```
var add = $(items).find('li').each(function() {

    return $(this).append('\n');
});
```

This gives me the following DOM output:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="image1"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image2"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image3"></a>
</li><li><a href="#"><img src="image4"></a>
</li><li><a href="#"><img src="image5"></a>
```

What I want is for the new line to be appended after the `</li>` tag. Like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="image1"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image2"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image3"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image4"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image5"></a></li>
```

I have realized that appending is not the right choice here but trying with `.after()` and `.before()` didn't produce any results either. In fact, both methods produce the same output:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="image1"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image2"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image3"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="image4"></a></li><li><a href="#"><img src="image5"></a></li>
```

So how can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

This is the example `php` code that is generating images. Of course there are other conditions that tells when to close `ul` and start a new one but this is what generates the new lines in source code and whitespaces between images:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$image.'" ><img src="'.$thumb.'"/></a></li>'."\n";
```

As said if I remove `\n` from `php`, then it's fine but the source code is then one-liner.

Comment: You want to write code that formats your source code? What's the point of this? Is this static code in a file or code being written from a server?

Comment: It's not even source code, it's all in memory, so formatting it in general seems wasteful. But there is a valid use case for `</li>\n<li>` vs. `</li><li>`, i.e. the items being styled with display: inline(-block), so the white space actually affects rendering.

Comment: That said it's 2018, use flexbox instead and don't rely on the white space quirk, just set the margins you want.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's being written from the server. As said below in the comment, the \n is making the code transparent when it's first loaded.(not everything in one line) But when I click load more images, there is no whitespace between images that are loaded next.

Comment: @user633551 My point is that in the very first comment, I asked you to clarify if this code was being written from a server and it wasn't until many comments later (and after an answer was posted) that you provided that information. That should have been stated in your question.

Comment: What should have been stated is the fact that the white space affects margins between elements, which is the case when these elements have display: inlinhae(-block), and I have only guessed that because it's a common problem and probably answered many times before (but usually it's the other way around: "how do I remove the margins between items")

Comment: What does your HTML look like without any JavaScript?

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews looks like the second snippet but when I click load more it's either 1st or 3rd example.

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` adds a new element *inside* the given element(s). You want `.after()`.

```
$(items).find("li").after("\n");
```

There's no need to use `.each()`, the DOM modification methods automatically operate on all the elements in the collection. And when using `.each()` you don't need to return anything, it always returns the original collection.

Note that there's little point in adding a newline *between* `<li>` elements, I don't think it will have any effect on the rendering of the list. Whitespace like this is useful in HTML source code, but it's irrelevant to the DOM.

Comment: You write such excellent answers, Barmar! It inspires me to write better answers.

Comment: Doesn't work. What you suggested is a short version of what have I already tried. The problem is that the PHP "\n" code is giving me white space between images and jquery doesn't. Looks unprofessional. Only thing I can do is to remove "\n" from PHP but I want the code to be structured, not all the stuff in one line

Comment: @user633551 You should probably deal with this using CSS padding or margins.

Comment: @user633551 If you're looking for spaces, you should use `&nbsp;` instead of `\n`

Comment: @Titus `&nbsp;` as a direct child of `<ul>` doesn't seem right.

Comment: @user633551 Your question is not tagged with `php` and you make no mention of it in your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sure I don't because it's working like it is supposed to. It's just jquery that's giving me headache :)

Comment: @user633551 Please update the question to clarify the problem you're really trying to solve. It seems like this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).